# Match a string if it comes after certain string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for JavaScript to match `John` (case insensitive) after `Name:`

I know how to do it, but I don't know how to get string from a different line like so (from a textarea):

```
Name
  John
```

This is what I tried to do :: `var str = /\s[a-zA-Z0-9](?= Name)/;`

The logic: get a string with letter/numbers on a linespace followed by Name.

Then, I would use the `.test();` method.

---

**EDIT:**

I tried to make the question more simple than it should have been.  The thing I don't quite understand is how do I isolate "John" (really anything) on a new line followed by a specific string (in this case `Name`).

---

E.g., **IF** `John` comes after `Name` {dosomething} else{dosomethingelse}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't support look-behinds. For something this simple, you can just match both parts of the string like this:

```
var str = /Name\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/;
```

You then just have to extract the first capture group if you want to get `John`. For example:

```
"Name\n John".match(/Name\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/)[1]; // John
```

However if you're just using `.test`, the capture group isn't necessary. For example:

```
var input = "Name\n John";
if (/Name\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+/.test(input)) {
    // dosomething
} else{
    // dosomethingelse
}
```

Also, if you need to ensure that `Name` and `John` appear on separate lines with nothing but whitespace in between, you can use this pattern with the multi-line (`m`) flag.

```
var str = /Name\s*^\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/m;
```

Comment: @plalx Looks like OP did too. (the sample string just has whitespace)

Comment: I agree that the OP seems confused, because he's contradicting himself. "match John (case insensitive) after Name:", then "The logic: get a string with letter/numbers on a linespace followed by Name."

Comment: @Matthew Can you edit the question to clarify what exactly you want? Do you want the text after `Name` or before it? And should it contain a colon (`Name:`)?

Comment: @Matthew Okay I've included an example which I hope will help. However, with your edit it sounds like a bit of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/213846). If that's the case, I'd recommend you put together a jsFiddle which demonstrates the problem as well as your best attempt to solve it so far and include that in a new question about what you're actually trying to achieve. Include a link back to this question if the context helps.

Comment: @p.s.w.g. You missed the order of pattern and string in your code above. It should look like this `/^Name\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test('Name\n John');`

Comment: @hex494D49 Whoops! Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a lookahead here, simply place **Name** before the characters you want to match. And to enable case-insensitive matching, place the `i` modifier on the end of your regular expression.

```
var str = 'Name\n   John'
var re  = /Name\s+[a-z0-9]+/i

if (re.test(str)) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Use the **String**.`match` method if you want to extract the name from the string.

```
'Name\n   John'.match(/Name\s+([a-z0-9]+)/i)[1];
```

The `[1]` here refers back to what was matched/captured in capturing group `#1`